# Segue Into another view without Nav Bar

Tags: ios, segue

I have created a new ios application using Single view application template in xcode 4.3 and added another view to that. In the first view i careated a command button as "show second view" and on second view i added a command buttion as "Show first view". I created a segue (of type push) from first view command buttion to second view.

When i click the "show second view" button from the first view, the second view comes up. But it comes up with the default navigation bar containing the default back buttion. I want to hide this navigation bar and present the second widow in full scrren without title bar. and when I click the "Show first view" on the second view I want to show the fist view.

How do I make it so the second view comes up but without the navigation bar?

Answer (score 2):

You can hide navigation bar by messaging this -

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:TRUE]
```

Answer (score 1):

A modalViewController might be better suited for this situation.