# OBJ-C - How can i change segue with a UIButton without a NavigationControl

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have tried with a `performSegueWithIdentifier` but I think I don't found a segue identifier. Perhaps is not possible without a navigation controller..

so my question is **How can i change segue with a UIButton without a NavigationControl?**

I am using XCode 4.5

Comment: i must conditionate the destination segue from 3 throw an uisegmentedcontrol and a uibutton

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Ray's Tutorial here... http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2

I don't actually know if it is possible without a Navigation Controller. Well, I am sure it is possible, but I am unsure how to accomplish it directly. Hopefully Ray's tutorial will point you in a direction.

This link might help too....  [Segue Into another view without Nav Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477030/segue-into-another-view-without-nav-bar)

Comment: Thanks at all, i solved using a navigation control without showing it

Answer (score 0):

You can set the seque identifier in interface builder if you click on the seque line.

Comment: When you ctrl-drag from a control to the a view controller

Comment: but like this i can't conditionate the action ?!

Comment: <pre>
- (IBAction)continueToSegues:(id)sender {
    if (self.destinationSelector.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"firstViewOrSegue" sender:self];
    else if (self.destinationSelector.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"secondViewOrSegue" sender:self];
}
<code>